# Deck card class in python

Tags: python, class, random

I am working on creating a class for the first time, and I am thinking that I have done every thing to get it run, but I still get bunch of issues which is `'list' object has no attribute 'shffule'` so the problem here is it will not shuffle the cards, and it will not tell the remaining cards, can any one tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
 import random

 class card_deck:
     def __init__(self, rank, suite, card):


        self.rank= rank
         self.suite = suite
    def ranks(self):
         return self.rank
    def suites(self):
         return self.suite
     def cards(self,card):
         suit_name= ['The suit of Spades','The suit of Hearts', 'The suit of Diamonds','Clubs']
         rank_name=['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King']


     def value(self):
         if self.rank == 'Ace':
             return 1
         elif self.rank == 'Jack':
             return 11
         elif self.rank == 'Queen':
             return 12
         elif self.rank == 'King':
             return 13
     def shffule(self):
         random.shuffle(self.cards)
     def remove(self,card):
         self.cards.remove(card)


     def cardremaining(self):
        self.suite-self.rank




 def main():
     try:
         deck=[]
         for i in ['Spades','Hearts', ' Diamonds','Clubs']:
         for c in ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King']:
                 deck.append((c, i))
         deck.shffule

         hand = []
         user =eval(input('Enter a number of cards: 1-7 '))
         print()
         while user <1 or user >7:
             print ("Only a number between 1-7:")
             return main()

         for i in range(user):
             hand.append(deck[i]) 
         print (hand)
     except ValueError:
         print("Only numbers")
         main()
```

Comment: shuffle is a method of card_deck class and you are trying to use it on a list. Convert your list to card_deck first.

Comment: I'd recommend not mistyping it everywhere, at very least.

Comment: Thank you, I got another issue here "      File "/Users/user/Desktop/deck_class.py", line 55, in main
    hand.append(deck[i])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @sashkello thanks for your help, it works now, but why rather than getting the card names I get [<class '__main__.card_deck'>, 0, 1, 2]

Comment: Because you need to print card name, not the class (create a separate method for it in your class, for example). Your interpreter doesn't know that you want to print name when you say to print an instance of a class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from your code containing many small errors; I will try to answer your main problems.

If you are going to use `shffule`*[sic]*  method of `card_deck` class, then you first need to create an instance of that class(whereas you tried to call that method with a list). Like this:

```
deck = card_deck(some_rank,some_suit,some_card)
deck.shffule() #Now you can call the method
```

Now, since you made it a class instance, you cannot get items from it like `hand.append(deck[i])`
Unless you defined the method `__getitem__` in your class definition, like this:

```
#this will be in your class definition
def __getitem__(self,i):
    return self.card_list[i] #Of course you have to define a list of cards in your class too.
```

In my opinion, you should spend a little more time trying to understand how is a class defined, how does methods work and how to access members of a class. After that you will be doing much better here

Comment: Thank you for your help, I do not know if I am asking a stupid question or not, but I will just go with it, when you answered the first question, deck = card_deck(rank=some_rank,suite=some_suit,card=some_card) what did you mean by rank=some_rank.... I mean I could not understand why should I put them there to make use of it, bear with me, I am so new, and I get so confused sometimes, it is my first language, and I am feeling so bad about it, because I sometimes feel that I am stupid enough to not be a computer sinc major!

Comment: Don't worry, it is OK. You just need to work with simpler stuff to grab the basic ideas. About the `deck = card_deck(...)` thing, you actually do not need to use it that way, I just wanted to show it explicitly. I updated the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually creating an instance of the card_deck class. The expression

```
deck=[]
```

creates a variable named deck referring to an empty list.

In python, [a, b, c,...] is the syntax for creating list literals.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Card = namedtuple('Card', 'sign, value')  #  no need to write class to represent card
SIGNS = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs']


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(sign, value) for sign in SIGNS for value in range(2,
                                                                             11) +
                      'J Q K A'.split()]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str([str(card) for card in self.cards])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.cards[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.cards[key] = value


deck = Deck()

print deck[11]  # indexing works, prints Card(sign='Hearts', value='K')

print len(deck)  # prints 52

print deck[13:16]  # slicing works

import random

random.shuffle(deck)  # shuffle works using no extra code
```